# Why did Qyburn use children for homicide?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* episode "The Winds of Winter", Qyburn uses aid of his "little birds" to assassinate

> Grand Maester Pycelle.

The children swarm the victim repeatedly stabbing him with short blades. I didn't really get that scene, he could just stab his target himself or use his knowledge to kill him through other means. Why involve more witnesses?

Comment: Taken into account that he's not a warrior he might have simply failed to stab him successfully.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong Stabbinb isn't really warrior-like act. Involving children means the same risk - and witnesses who exchange information for sweets.

Comment: Not if you involve several attackers. In my understanding it was just a safer method.

Comment: Question is now showing up in Hot Questions. Title is a spoiler, please amend.

Comment: @chucksmash is this that spoilery? The title doesn't say who he killed, all show watchers know that Qyborn controls the children, and there's a similar (but not the same) scene in the books so it doesn't spoil book only readers.

Comment: Out of story, because it is creepy. In story... maybe it is a good bonding activity?

Comment: @chucksmash We can't have every single question titled "Why did this character did that?". The title doesn't spoil any major event of the series.

Comment: @TomášZato It kind of does? I had no idea the little birds would be assassinating anybody. Through process of elimination and some of the other spoilery titles that have made it into Hot Questions since the episode aired ("How did SPOILER legitimise their claim on the SPOILER?" or something like that...) I'm definitely not going in unspoilt when I watch it tonight. *shrug*, feel free to play the world's tiniest violin of course.

Comment: His little birds each have some levels in the Rogue class. As such, they can perform sneak attacks when they are flanking, as seen in the episode.

Comment: I could also picture Qyburn ensuring compliance by using some kind of addictive substance in the sweets he gives the kids. Randomly, I also see them being the ones to kill Arya for some reason. - or she might have to kill a whole bunch of them, it would fit with the theme of her losing her humanity.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**One word: Training.**

An old man trapped in a room won't likely be the last Westerosian that Qyburn wants dead. It's now clear that his approach to scaling his organization is by using destitute children.  Which makes sense, (once you get past any moral revulsion you might have): they're  malleable, desperate for someone who cares about them, and aren't considered a threat by others.

Qyburn's *developing a team*, and we know that the teams' goals include:

- Spying on Qyburn's - or Cercei's - frenemies
- Killing their enemies, including some that likely can't be dispatched via mass-wildfyre-bombings

So, if you want to turn kids into assassins that can take out *real threats* someday, you'd likely need to do two things:

- Let them practice the physical skills involved, and
- Desensitize them to the natural moral resistance, or their fear of new things

Both of those are achieved by making them start with victims that pose no threat in controlled, supervised environments.

(If he's read the hot management tomes of the era, I assume he's already had them *watch* a mass stabbing prior to this scene's events, and will encourage them to *teach* a mass stabbing to the next class of urchins to really lock it in.)

Comment: Also note that these children are Varys' little birds, so they may already have been used to work as agents. Whether that included murder, we don't know, but it stands to reason that their life on the street will at least have hardened them to some degree.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is as simple as Qyburn would never put himself in a position that could cause himself harm. He is a "mad scientist" and every mad scientist needs henchmen. Pycell was known to be crafty and deceitfully spry for his age. If one of the little birds gets injured or killed, it is no great loss.

The witnesses are already in on the Wildfire plot, so using them to kill one more person really is not that big of a deal...